# google maps displaying partially

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I am currently banging my head on this issues with google maps API3. The map loads partially in the top right corner, but then when I refresh the page, the maps displays fully. 
Here is an example:

https://sites.google.com/site/dferrai/home/Sentieri%20ischitani%202014-02-28%2010-06-15.png

All the parent divs have the height set to 100%. I believe the issue is very similar to the one people are experiencing when using Jquery mobile. As you can see I am not using Jquery mobile but I am managing pages in the same way. Each page is a section and they are all contained in one page and displayed as needed with the use of Javascript. Obviously the map loads before the section is made visible and there the glitches start. Any ideas on how to solve it? 
Here is my simplified code: http://jsfiddle.net/elektray/V9LxT/1/

```
    /*Script for maps*/

    var lat, lon;

    function onBodyLoad()
    {
    console.log("subscribing to the deviceready event");
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    function onDeviceReady () {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onGeoSuccess, onGeoError);
    }

    function onGeoSuccess(position) {
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lon = position.coords.longitude;
    var currentposition = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);
    console.log("currentposition " + currentposition);
    var mapoptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: currentposition,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapoptions);
    var iconBase = 'images/';

    /*Create marker for user current position*/
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: currentposition,
        map: map,
        icon: iconBase + 'my-location.svg'
    });

    console.log("creating map1");

    /*Create marker for walks starting points with info dialog*/

    var walk1Start = new google.maps.LatLng (59.32522, 18.07002);

    var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
        '<div class="siteNotice">'+
        '</div>'+
        '<h2 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Walk1</h2>'+
        '<div id="bodyContent">'+
        '<p>Prima linea di decrizione ' +
        'Senconda linea di decrizione '+
        'Heritage Site.</p>'+

        '</div>'+
        '</div>';

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });


    var walk1Marker = new google.maps.Marker ({
        position: walk1Start,
        map: map,
        icon: iconBase + 'map-icon-hover.svg',
        title: "Walk 1"
    });

        google.maps.event.addListener(walk1Marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map,walk1Marker);
    });

    /*Script to adjust map view to all markers*/

    //  Make an array of the LatLng's of the markers you want to show
    var LatLngList = new Array (currentposition, walk1Start);
    //  Create a new viewpoint bound
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds ();
    //  Go through each...
    for (var i = 0, LtLgLen = LatLngList.length; i < LtLgLen; i++) {
        //  And increase the bounds to take this point
        bounds.extend (LatLngList[i]);
    }
  //  Fit these bounds to the map
    map.fitBounds (bounds);
    }

    function onGeoError(error) {
       if( error == 1) {
        alert('Turn on Geolocation services.');
    }
    }
```

I appreciate your help

Thanks

Comment: I don't see a map at all in your Fiddle?

Comment: fiddle contains no CSS - but yes, try a fixed width and height of 500px by 500px to get the map working and take it from there.

Comment: Look at the [google.maps.Map resize event](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map): `Developers should trigger this event on the map when the div changes size: google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize') .` (if you really have the map size fully specified)

Comment: If you've researched this, then you should have figured out the problem only occurs when the map is loaded inside of hidden elements.  When you show the map, then call the `resize` function which forces the tiles the load again.  See answers below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call this when you make the map visible:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
```

Answer (score 0):

**After** you have initialised the map try

```
window.onresize = function() {  google.maps.event.trigger(map,'resize'); }
```

More info at the **[Google API Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference)** - - F3 / look up 'resize'